# Inserts become increasingly slow over time?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I have a simple `console app` written in `C#` with `VS.NET 2012`. I'm using a simple database with `Entity Framework 5` (model first). I have two tables, **Customer**, and **Email**. Every email record has a reference to a customer record.

I create the customer and email object, save them to the collection in the `EF` context, and after 1000 records have been created, I call save changes on the context. The batches of 1000 become increasingly slow, starting out with 1 minute for 1000, and then by the 9000th record, the batches of 1000 take 4 minutes to complete.

I am reading the data out of a `CSV` file one line at a time, doing a simple split on each line, and then constructing the simple objects.

My question is whether this is `EF5`, or if I'm missing an `index` on the database? I'm doing no other pre-processing. I'm using `SQL Server 1012`.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942176/60108)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DbContext` tracks all objects, even after they are saved. The size of the `DbContext` is probably what is causing your application to become slow.

I recommend disposing the `DbContext` and creating a new `DbContext` after 1000 inserts.

Comment: This improved things, although it's still 3x slower than using the SQL helper classes and stored procs. But there's another problem, it seems by not calling save on every new record, that queries to that context fail to see the newly added and yet to be saved records, could that be true?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the track of object using this

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```